# How does findViewById can return something different from View and the program will still compiled?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, methods, view

I'm shocked :) and feel embraced to ask such a question but I can figure it out. I have a TextView that is part of my *View*.
How does the following code is compiled:

```
 val shouldBeTextView : String= view.findViewById(R.id.justSomething)
```

I looked at the method signature and saw that it returns a *View* or a subtype, but String,Int,etc (they all works) **aren't** *View*'s?
Maybe the compiler it tired? :)
I must say I have never had such an issue in Java

Comment: Does it ends with class cast exception ? or shouldBeTextView contains View.ToString() ?

Comment: @Selvin, cast to Int throw an exception.. Other casts I will try tomorrow.. Computer is dead..

Comment: @Selvin, getting exception also for String :)

Comment: so it seems like Kotlin's compiler is not cheking T constraints for `T findViewById(int)`

Comment: @Selvin, the way I understand it, the compiler cast the right side to the type of the left side.. In run time exception occurs.. I don't think it's a generic (T) issue

Comment: yes, it is ... it can cast becase method looks like `<T> T method()` ... of course for `View` is `<T exttends View> T findViewById(int)` but it seems like Kotlin doesn't check  `T` constraint if it comes from java

Comment: The cast is on the returned value of findViewById... it is not part of the method

Comment: it doesn't matter it's in findViewTraversal  just add java class with  `public static <S extends String> S method(Object i){ return (S) i;}` then in Kotlin use `val test : Int? = Test.method("0");` bang ... it compiles ... bit obviously it will cause ClassCastException

Comment: @Selvin, did you try it?

Answer (score -1):

This is due to Koltin's [typing and casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) system. Kotlin is smart enough to see that you are expecting a string in the variable and casts behind the scenes using [`View.toString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#toString()), as long as there exists a way t cast the receviedd type to the expected the assignment will workr without ssues. All of the following are roughly equivalent

```
val shouldBeTextView : String = view.findViewById(R.id.justSomething)

val shouldBeTextView : String = view.findViewById(R.id.justSomething).toString()

val shouldBeTextView : String = view.findViewById(R.id.justSomething) as String
```

Comment: well, every Object in Java has `toString()` method ... hehe  "we add null safety, but set you on another mine"

Comment: @puffin, so for Int It will cast it : *as Int* ?

Comment: @Selvin, sorry but I didn't understand you

Comment: he wrote : *casts and behind the scenes using View.toString()* if it's true then every java's object in kotlin can be assigned to val of String type ... again if it's true, then it's a mine (land mine) same as null in java (at least for Kotlin's developers)

Comment: @DorVak it will only cast if you are explicitly asking for an Int such as `val view: Int = ...` IIf you do not specify the type the no cast will occur

Comment: @Selvin As saidd above, kotlin will only make those casts on an explicit assignment to a string variable, asked for with `toString`, or used in string interpolation (which uses the implicit casting system)

Comment: @puffin, you wrote in your post that all the there are equivalent. When you writing as String, method toString runs?!? because if not, programmer may think he have a String but actually it's a View instance

Comment: instead complain at compile time: hello developer, are you sure you wana do that ?

Comment: @DorVak Yes, `toString` is called in the backend when the `as` operator is used

Comment: @Selvin, it is not the issue mate. Unfortunately shit happens, and issue like this can take a lot of time to investigate. So i'm trying to understand the exact behavior

Comment: @DorVak  *it is not the issue mate. Unfortunately shit happens, and issue like this* you should decide if it's an issue or not :D

Comment: @Selvin It wouldn't make a whole lot of sense to complain about something the programmer has explicitly asked for. If it did, the programmer would need to create intermediary string variables just to print an object to the terminal using a similar method as described here

Comment: @puffin, and what happens to Int for example? If i'm attempting to assign the return value into an Int variable or any other variable the view can not be cast to?

Comment: @DorVak You'll get a compile time warning if it *cannot* be cast to the specified type, but in this case the View can be be cast to a string so Kotlin gives no complaints because the programmer explicitly asked for a string

Comment: @puffin, thanks friend. But I checked it with many other types and didn't get a warning. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @DorVak Try printing the values you are receiving, that might give you more insight into what exactly is being done to the View you're receiving. if you get no warning it means that kotlin found some way to cast the view sucessfully.